# Embed Text at Scenario-level for cucumber-reports

Tags: android, cucumber, automated-tests, appium, cucumber-jvm

**Background**

I am using appium with cucumber-jvm with gradle build tool to run tests for Android.

So,when i generate reports,i want to see some custom text in the reports.
The custom text can be embedded in the reports for each Scenario at the Step level(For this i used `Scenario.Write()` and my text is embedded successfully).

**Query**

But now,i wanted to add some text at the Scenario level,let's say add DeviceId of the Device ,on which the Scenario ran(i.e. i could embed DeviceId along with the Scenario Name itself).

If i am able to make sense to the reader,through above statements,Please do leave your suggestions ,as to how this task can be done.

Comment: I am guessing you are asking for Scenario Outline case? Like having a dynamic description for each scenario involved? Is this correct?

Comment: @Grasshopper
yes ,totally agree.any thoughts to do this!

Answer (score 3):

You can make the description of the scenario outline dynamic by putting in placeholders similar to what is done for steps. The relevant values will be pulled out from the examples table.

```
Scenario Outline: SO desc <sno> <devid>
    Given Hello Serial No <sno> device id <devid>

    Examples:
    | sno | devid |
    | 1 | device 1 |
    | 2 | device2 |
```

Comment: nice answer,but in runtime,i have no control on which device will be used for test execution,so the sequenced list of devices i put in the Examples ,maynot be the order in which the devices are used for executing.

It would be great,if we could put the deviceId dynamically!.
Please let me know,if it sounds logical and whether it would be possible using the method you gave.

I saw an example similar to this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640200/cucumber-scenario-outline-and-examples-with-generic-step-definitions`

However it works for Step Level,not at Scenario Level.

Comment: Can you add some relevant portions of the feature file for reference as I am a bit confused what you are looking for. Thx

Comment: [![Scenario example](https://s24.postimg.org/y0a7v8txx/Screen_Shot_2017_01_26_at_7_34_14_PM.png)](example scenario)