# Calling Steps from Step Definitions

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber

I am creating a feature file where to call other steps from other scenario . Please find the below and suggest if missing anything.

Feature File :

Feature: Test Multiple Steps

```
Scenario: Print All console
    Given Print the start console
    Given Print All console
do
step "Print the console for numbers"
step "Print first numbers console"
step "Print second numbers console"
end

Scenario: Print All console
    Given Print the console for numbers
    Then Print first numbers console
    Then Print second numbers console
```

Step Definitions:

```
import { Then, Given } from 'cucumber';

Given(/^Print the start console$/, async () => {
    console.log('------Printing console-----');
});


Then(/^Print All console$/, async () => {
    console.log('------Printing all console-----');
});


Given(/^Print the console for numbers$/, async () => {
    console.log('------Printing console for numbers-----');
});


Then(/^Print first numbers console$/, async () => {
    console.log('------Printing first number console-----');
});

Then(/^Print second numbers console$/, async () => {
    console.log('------Printing second number console-----');
});
```

While executing I receive an error as below . Please help.

[12:21:35] E/launcher - Error: Error: Parse error in 'src\features\multipleSteps.feature': (6:5): expected: #EOF, #TableRow, #DocStringSeparator, #StepLine, #TagLine, #ScenarioLine, #ScenarioOutlineLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'do'

Comment: Remove the code in the feature file. The do and the step lines. The error message mentions it also at the end - got 'do'

Comment: Then , how to call those steps . Intention is to reuse the steps . Should it be removed from feature file and added in Step Definition file? Then please help with the syntax

Comment: Code should be in step definition

Comment: can you please help in forming the syntax. I am trying to use typescript and the syntax doesnt work.
Then(/^Print All console$/, async () => {
    do
        step "Print the console for numbers";
    step "Print first numbers console";
    step "Print second numbers console";
    end
    console.log('------Printing all console-----');
});

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scenario Outline 
Like:

Scenario Outline : Print All console

```
Given Print the start console

Given Print All “<console>”
```

Examples:

|console|

| Print the console for numbers |

| Print first numbers console |

| Print second numbers console |

Take a reference here: 
[Cucumber scenario outline and examples with generic step definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640200/cucumber-scenario-outline-and-examples-with-generic-step-definitions)